# Weka installing libsvm

Tags: java, eclipse, classification, weka, libsvm

I'm trying to use libsvm in weka from java.  I've added the libsvm jar to classpath, including the weka jar.

Weka version: 3-6

Image here: http://tinypic.com/r/14xhycz/8

Libsvm works in the weka user interface, but I still have the error 'libsvm classes not in classpath', when trying to use weka in java.

I haven't included 'WLSVM' because I haven't been able to download it (website down at the moment: http://www.cs.iastate.edu/~yasser/wlsvm/).  Do I need to download this for libsvm to work?

I've restarted Eclipse a number of times, not that this would make a different I'm sure.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an appropriate reference path to the lib in your Eclipse project. So, go to Eclipse Luna for example (check the appropriate way to include in others versions [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_an_extra_library_to_my_project%27s_classpath%3F)), and then enable support for your library.

> **Project(Alt+Enter)** >> **Java Build Path** >> **Add JARs**

or

> **Project(Alt+Enter)** >> **Java Build Path** >> **Add External JARs**

I prefer the first approach, because I can put a library inside the project as a lib folder and then pick it on Eclipse menu options.

Comment: Well, I thought this was an intelligent question, and didn't have an obvious answer, but there you go! Cheers!

Comment: Your question is very interesting. I used Weka and it is powerful tool. Sometimes, the answers to the problems are in the front of ours eyes; in these case, we need more inspiration to resolve them that when we created. best regards.